# Getting additional empty line

Tags: java

When I run this code I am getting additional line after I enter the the first number and  before this prints staircase.

```
6


     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

You can see the additional line between 6 and the staircase

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
        System.out.print(new String(new char[n-i]).replace("\0", " "));
        System.out.print(new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", "#"));
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first iteration you are printing `n` blanks and zero `#`.

Initializing `i = 1` in the loop will print only `n-1` blanks before printing one `#`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @guy's answer, just initialize `i` to 1 and that should fix your problem.

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
```